# Can I do Android Programming in C++, C?

Tags: c++, android

Can I do Android programming in C++, C? If the answer is "yes" then please tell how? And what's the procedure to set up?

I don't know Obj-C, Java, but well-versed in C, C++, Flash AS3, SDK released by Google.

Please do not tell about NVDIA SDK it's not fully developed :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**PLEASE NOTE: THE ANSWER BELOW IS HORRIBLY OUTDATED, AND MIGHT NOT BE ENTIRELY CORRECT ANYMORE.**

You can program in C/C++ using the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html#overview). You'll have to wrap your c++ codebase in a static library and load that through a Java wrapper & JNI.

The standard NDK does not support RTTI and a lot of the functionality of standard c++ is also not available such as std::string, etc. To solve this you can recompile the NDK. Dmitry Moskalchuk supplies a modified version of the NDK that supports this at http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r3.php. This modified version works on all Android phones that run on an ARM processor.

Depending on the kind of application you should decide to use Java or C/C++. I'd use C/C++ for anything that requires above average computational power and games -- Java for the rest.

Just pick one language and write the majority of your application in that language; JNI calls can decrease your performance by a lot. Java isn't that hard though -- if you know how to program in C/C++. The advantage of Java is that the application can run on any device running Android, where as NDK applications depend on the architecture it was compiled for.

Comment: The answer itself Id assume. If any other answer is horribly outdated or even outright wrong, vote or comment accordingly. A particular answer itself might have some value even if details are outdated due to environmental changes (like a new language, SDK changes or disappearance of a platform).  Refer to yourself(the answer) and the question.

Answer (score 15):

You should use Android NDK to develop performance-critical portions of your apps in native code. See [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html#overview).

Anyway i don't think it is the right way to develop an entire application.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can program Android apps in C++ (for the most part), using the [Native Development Kit (NDK)](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html), although Java is the primary/preferred language for programming Android, and your C++ code will likely have to interface with Java components, and you'll likely need to read and understand the documentation for Java components, as well. Therefore, I'd advise you to use Java unless you have some existing C++ code base that you need to port and that isn't practical to rewrite in Java.

Java is very similar to C++, I don't think you will have any problems picking it up... going from C++ to Java is incredibly easy; going from Java to C++ is a little more difficult, though not terrible. [Java for C++ Programmers](http://triton.towson.edu/~mzimand/os/Lect2-java-tutorial.html) does a pretty good job at explaining the differences. Writing your Android code in Java will be more idiomatic and will also make the development process easier for you (as the tooling for the Java Android SDK is significantly better than the corresponding NDK tooling)

In terms of setup, Google provides the [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) IDE for both Java and C++ Android development (with Gradle as the build system), but you are free to use whatever IDE or build system you want so long as, under the hood, you are using the Android SDK / NDK to produce the final outputs.

Comment: "Java is very similar to C++"?

Comment: @Alek what's your objection? It is true. Syntactically, the two languages are very similar, with Java borrowing very heavily from C++.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan That's only true as long as the languages are compared from a very superficial point of view. The syntax is indeed similar (as it is the case for many popular languages -- C, C#, JS, PHP, ...), but paradigms and idioms are different. While Java still focuses on classes despite recent influences of functional elements, C++ has already early provided a whole range of abstraction mechanisms (global functions, templates, typedef, functors, operator overloading, ...), which leads to a different programming style. E.g. STL and Java Collections are structured very differently.

Comment: There is nothing similar about them except that they are both OO. One is manual memory managed and the other is garbage collected. That enough is a huge difference. One runs native, the other runs in a VM, one has a preprocessor, the other does not. Can you make direct system calls in java? No. It's all abstracted. One is highly portable while the other is not. Totally different. The syntax is not even close the same. Show me where I am using <T> in Java please.

Comment: @Rafael they are more similar than you may realize. C++ has explicit memory management, but also allows for reference counted and garbage collected data using smart pointer classes. Java *typically* runs in a virtual machine, but it is also possible to compile Java bytecode down to native code (which is commonly done in a just-in-time manner, but there are also ahead-of-time compilers like GCJ which can produce a native executable from Java bytecode); likewise, C++ is typically compiled directly to native code, but  LLVM and NativeClient are examples of compiling C++ to portable bytecode.

Comment: @Rafael Java doesn't allow one to make native calls directly, but it does support the "native" keyword and supports the Java Native Interface (JNI), which allows for Java to call into native code. Also, the syntax is, in fact, extremely close; both C++ and Java are a part of the C familly of languages; if you compare their syntax to that of LISP or Python, it will be quite evident that they share similar syntax. And, yes, you do use "<T>"  in Java; in Java, that feature is called "generics".

Comment: Unless JCG is thoroughly used, Java has to JIT. Not only does it JIT but it continually re-JITs until it thinks somehing is as optimal as it can make it. It usually uses an interpretter at first, which is often pretty slow, and then it often doesn't really do a great job of optimization for quite a while. I did a comparison test just for my own benefit, once, and wrote some Python functions that outperformed equivalent Java functions by a factor of 10. After Java had executed the functions about 100 times, it eventually *almost* became as fast as Python was out of the gate.

Comment: I know that is not everyone's experience, many people often say that Java is way faster than Python, but that's been my experience every time I've tried it. When I've brought my work to the attention of experienced Java programmers, they were not able to get Java to do any better. The general Java environment has a long and sordid history of being buggy and resource hoggy. When Google chose Java for Android I wasn't quite in murder suicide mode, but I was very bummed. From my point of view it was one of the bigger tragedies of our tech times.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [MoSync](https://github.com/MoSync/MoSync) too, MoSync gives you standard C/C++, easy-to-use well-documented APIs, and a full-featured Eclipse-based IDE.  Its now a open sourced IDE still pretty cool but not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look also at C++ Builder XE6, and XE7 supports android in c++ code, and with Firemonkey library.

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder

Pretty easy way to start, and native code. But the binaries have a big size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android NDK, but answers should note that the Android NDK app is not free to use and there's no clear open source route to programming Android *on* Android in an increasingly Android-driven market that began as open source, with Android developer support or the extensiveness of the NDK app, meaning you're looking at abandoning Android as any kind of first steps programming platform without payments.

Note: I consider subscription requests as payments under duress and this is a freemium context which continues to go undefeated by the open source community.

Comment: Could you please explain more, I didn't catch the point.

Answer (score -5):

There is more than one library for working in C++ in Android programming:

1. C++ - qt (A Nokia product, also available as LGPL)
2. C++ - Wxwidget (Available as GPL)