# Is it possible to generate a Local Buffer Overflow in Android via a compiled binary to gain root access?

Tags: android, c++, root, buffer-overflow

I want to know if it is possible rooting any Android OS via Local Buffer Overflow , which I would generate using a compiled program that will contain the most simplest Local Buffer Overflow:

```
char buf[BUFSIZE]; 
gets(buf);
```

And the once I would compile that program I would push that binary in the /storage to be executed via shell run by ADB, so is it possible to do what I said?

And if yes how I would reverse engineer a crash to develop an exploit that would gain root access for me in the device?

Comment: No you can't, because java has a runtime environment that checks for such things and prevents overflows from being exploitable.

Comment: @Andreas Vogl A shell binary is not executed in Java runtime. But, AFAIK, such an exploit will be handled on Linux level.

Comment: @Onik So it is possible? cause I was thinking that I can generate vulnerable compiled binary and push it to the device, but the thing is that I don't know how I would debug an Local Overflow crash in android via adb? 

I've seen people done it, like for example the famous exploit: ZergRush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many good articles about android rooting, such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android_OS)). They explain that rooting android devices is done by using exploits (bugs) in the android os, aka firmware.

Buffer overflows have never been involved in rooting android devices.

While technically achieving a buffer overflow is possible using [NDK and native C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773650/can-i-do-android-programming-in-c-c), there is a long, long way to go from a buffer overflow to gaining root access.

As MSalters has pointed out correctly, your C code will run on a linux stack. There are quite a few *serious* defensive measures in place, that prevent easy exploiting of buffer overflows.

If you don't want to accept "no" as an answer, let's say: "highly unlikely and probably not worth your time" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. In the end, this is just Linux. A program running under a non-root account cannot gain root permissions by either intentional or unintentional methods.

Comment: Then how rooting works from programming aspect? As from what I knew from what I read in the internet, I found that rooting works mostly using buffer overflow's because when memory which is used by a function that is driven from a system level and not user level is overflowed this tells you can overflow the memory with some amount of bytes, so lets suppose the memory used here by "gets()" is 500 bytes then (4 Bytes EIP Redirection to sh Binary in memory + 465 Bytes of Junk + 31 Bytes for sh Binary) by injecting the following we can get root access because the memory is a system level memory.

Comment: Can you please explain how rooting programmatically works if that's not that way?

Comment: @0x01Brain: That assumes an existing binary which _does_ run under root. Your apps do not.

Comment: I'm not talking about "Java" apps I'm talking about a compiled "C" binary that is compiled for Android if you know what I mean.

Comment: You seems to not understand what Buffer Overflows does, if you read more about it you will know what I meant exactly.

Comment: @0x01Brain: I HAVE written compiled C++ code for Android. Didn't run as root either. And as you can see from the lack of other answers, it appears the other 7 million Stack Overflow users agree with my answer.